# Terraform : can I have 2 local block with same key but with different value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have following local block, observe the `domain` key

```
locals {
  organization = "xxxx"
  domain       = "cs"
  env = {
    prod = "prod"
    stg  = "stg"
    dev  = "dev"
  }
}

locals {
  s3_artifact_bucket_name = {
    prod = join("-", [
      local.s3_artifact_bucket_name_prefix,
      local.env["prod"]
    ])
    stg = join("-", [
      local.s3_artifact_bucket_name_prefix,
      local.env["stg"]
    ])
    dev = join("-", [
      local.s3_artifact_bucket_name_prefix,
      local.env["dev"]
    ])
  }
  s3_artifact_bucket_name_prefix = join("-", [
    local.organization,
    local.domain,
    local.s3_bucket_awsresource,
    local.s3_artifact_bucket_purpose
  ])
  s3_bucket_awsresource = join("-", [
    "bucket",
    var.cd_account_id
  ])
  s3_artifact_bucket_purpose = "artifacts-iac"
}
```

local.domain ( cs) is being used to create some another local name.

now I want to add another local block with same domain but different value ( as there are 3 values for domain ) and create another local name for s3 bucket  with `common` as value inside it.

```
locals {
  # placeholder for access logs bucket name
  domain = "common"
  s3_bucket_awsresource = join("-", [
    "bucket",
    var.cd_account_id
  ])
  s3_bucket_purpose         = "s3-access-logs"
  access_logs_bucket_region = "us-east-1"
}
```

here in the next step I want to reference local.domain as `common` and not `cs`

```
locals {
  s3_artifact_access_logs_bucket_name = join("-", [local.organization, local.domain, s3_bucket_awsresource, local.s3_bucket_purpose, local.access_logs_bucket_region])
}
```

I am afraid `local.domain` will point out to which domain key and value? is there a way to use `domain` as key but with different value.

Comment: "use domain as key" - a key for what? Can you provide other example of what you want to do?

Comment: ＠Marcin updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot have a duplicate `local` in the same workspace.

Consider making a map instead (as you have done with `env`) or perhaps a list containing the three values, then using another control variable to select which value to use.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I will post my solution too for better understanding of others

Answer (score 2):

Thank to @Ben and @Calin, I was able to solve it,

Posting it for better understanding, `using a map for the same key` solved my problem

```
locals {
  organization = "xxx"
  domain = {
    customer_service = "cs"
    common           = "common"
  }
  env = {
    prod = "prod"
    stg  = "stg"
    dev  = "dev"
  }
}





locals {
  s3_artifact_access_logs_bucket_name = join("-", [
    local.organization,
    local.domain["common"],
    local.s3_bucket_awsresource,
    local.s3_access_logs_bucket_suffix
  ])

  s3_access_logs_bucket_suffix = join("-", [
    local.s3_acess_logs_bucket_purpose,
    local.s3_access_logs_bucket_region
  ])
  s3_acess_logs_bucket_purpose = "s3-access-logs"
  s3_access_logs_bucket_region = "us-east-1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won’t work. Instead, you can define domain as a `map`, just like `env`, and create three different keys with three different values.

Comment: Since @Ben was first to answer I had to accept his answer, but you were right!